# Find checkboxes that are checked with a specific class

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of jquery below - it's finding all the checkbox inputs that are checked.

I want to make this more specific - is it possible to add to the find selector with something like "find all inputs that are checked that have a class called correct"?

```
    $(this).find("input:checked").each(function(){
        checkedlist.push($(this).val());
    });
```

If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply add the class to your selector:

```
$(this).find("input.correct:checked").each(function () {
    checkedlist.push( this.value );
});
```

---

For a tiny boost in performance, you can remove the `:checked` part from your selector:

```
$(this).find("input.correct").each(function () {
    if ( this.checked ) checkedlist.push( this.value );
});
```