# Targeting specific class with .find

Tags: jquery

As a continuation of this question - [Find checkboxes that are checked with a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956629/find-checkboxes-that-are-checked-with-a-specific-class)

Is it possible to do the same with this jquery - I only want to target specifically the checkbox inputs with the class "correct"?

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question").length > 0) {
            toggleInputs($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question")[0]);        
        }
    });
});

function toggleInputs(questionElement) {
    if ($(questionElement).data('max-answers') == undefined) {
        return true;
    } else {
        maxAnswers = parseInt($(questionElement).data('max-answers'), 10); 
        if ($(questionElement).find(":checked").length >= maxAnswers) {
            $(questionElement).find(":not(:checked)").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
            $(questionElement).find("input[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The selector for class is one of the most common/basic jQuery selectors - it would just be `.correct`. Where do you want to add it? What are you in doubt about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox].correct").click(function (e) {
        if ($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question").length > 0) {
            toggleInputs($(e.currentTarget).closest("div.question")[0]);        
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $checkboxes = $('input.correct:checkbox");
```

Comment: I think this is valid only for css3